# 0-1 V to 4-20 mA converter

Tags: voltage, current

I was just going through circuits for conversion of 0-1 V to 4-20 mA. I just got this on google, but unable to figure out why those transistors are required in the circuit. I have attached the circuit diagram here

Thanks for help !

[image]

Comment: Basically the transistor in the feedback circuit allows to vary the current output giving a voltage feedback; so the op-amp will see the voltage, but will act on the Base of the transistor which will in turn generate a current

Comment: Put component designators on this schematic and I can walk you thru it.  No, I'm not going to keep saying stuff like "the second from bottom resistor on the emitter of the left transistor".  It doesn't matter whether you drew this or someone else.  It's your job to present a schematic properly here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop plz consider them omamp1, opamp2, BJT1, BJT2. Plz explain using these notations

Comment: @PrashantSingh may I suggest you to use this [editor](https://www.circuitlab.com/) to redraw the circuit and post a snapshot? Olin is right, it's easier if you use component designators, and doing it outside the schematic is a pain for both

Comment: @Parshant: No, such hand waving is ambiguous and a hassle when writing about the circuit.  Since you are unwilling to provide a reasonable schematic, all that's left is to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st Op Amp, U1 together with 1st transistor, properly labeled Q1 is a common emitter inverting amplifier with Vbe nulled out by emitter feedback to input.

The 2nd stage provides an inverting voltage to current converter with open collector PNP current source to drive the loop.

1st Variable resistor should be called VR1 is to adjust the 4mA level by creating a DC input offset.  VR2 adjusts the gain to 1V input change for 16mA output change (20-4)

Comment: I've read it again. And again. Can't make anything of it. What is "IA"? What does "Vbe nulled out by emitter feedback" mean? Please describe it better. This isn't helpful.

Comment: YOu know OA's have high gain so input differential voltage can be considered near zero volts. Now  the emitter of NPN is unity gain buffered output of OA, U1 with a 0.6V offset from Vbe. However that is compensated by a higher 0.6Vdc offset from U1 since the inverting input must match the non-inverting input with a negative feedback loop. The non-inverting feedback ratio is <<1 since Rbe is much lower than R+ VR2 (1K) so the non-inverting gain from + is 1+ inverting gain, the overall gain is still near unity with some calibration from VR2 (1K).

Comment: overall gain is still near unity with some calibration from VR2 (1K) to compensate for attenuation caused by (VR1 + 39K) /(10K + (VR1 + 39K)) =80 ~ 95% , so DC offset adjust also affects gain. not a great design but works